# GNU parallel interactive mode. How to make chunk request instead of request for each job?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu, interactive, gnu-parallel

Is it possible to make chunk request instead of request for each job?

`function $1 $2 $3 | parallel --gnu --group --interactive -k -j 4 function_run {}`

In that case, GNU Parallel is asking question to run each job, but i want question to run next chunk of 4 parallel jobs. And it would be great, if I could change -j in run process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-j` can read from a file: If the file changes, it will be re-read after each job stops. The content is the same as you would give to `-j` (e.g. `4`, `100%`, or `-1`).

If you want `--interactive` for chunks of 4 jobs, then you could write a wrapper:

```
run4() {
  parallel echo ::: "$@"
}
export -f run4
seq 10 | parallel -n4 --interactive run4
run4 1 2 3 4 ?...y
run4 5 6 7 8 ?...n
run4 9 10 ?...n
```

(--group is default).